# trouble installing with Zend framework on wamp server

Tags: zend-framework

I Download the zend Framework 1.12.3 and rename with Zend and place this folder in 
"C:\wamp\bin\php\" 
and now i right click on 'my computer properties' and select 
'Advanced->Environment Variables' and create a new

'user variable' variable name: zf and variable value: C:\wamp\bin\php\Zend\bin

and edit 'System variable->Path' where at the end of variable value i placed ';C:\wamp\bin\php\Zend\bin;'

after that i open 'php.ini' file and edit 
; Windows: "\path1;\path2" 
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;C:\wamp\bin\php\Zend\library" 
and restart wamp

and go to cmd and type 'C:\wamp\bin\php\Zend\bin>zf show version'

but i always get a message

'"php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

please help to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add path of your php.exe in **Path** variable.

select 'Advanced->Environment Variables' 
In System variables: 
modify **Path** with php-path
exemple: ";c:\php" (without comma)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking....you don't need to change or add any Environment Variables.
Just put zend's "library" folder in your project directory.
And it will work.It wored for me.
So your directory structure will be :

C:\wamp\YOUR-project-folder\library

Directory structure :

```
YOUR-project-folder
  - application
  - docs
  - library
  - public
  - test
```